# scroll go to the top page

Tags: asp.net

net use web methods to save data from JavaScript when i press save the all page go the top how i can save state position after post back

Comment: How i can prevent go to the top page

Answer (score 1):

You can set it programmatically

```
Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
```

In the page declaration

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Or in the web.configs `<system.web>` section.

```
<pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

Comment: How i can prevent go to the top page

Answer (score 0):

The reason the page is returning to the top, is because it is being Submitted and hence reloaded.

If you want to keep the position of the page you have 2 options;

1) Use a Anchor (See: http://www.hypergurl.com/anchors.html)
2) Post your form using AJAX and then you do not need to reload the page

Option 2 is the prefered, if you are using webforms you could use an AJAX Update Panel, or if you are using MVC you can do it using JQuery.

Comment: How i can prevent go to the top page

Answer (score 0):

try to setting the following page directive in your page

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Comment: How i can prevent go to the top page

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question, and my method of doing this was the following:

I  put a `javascript:void(0)` in an `a` tag, as shown here:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
```