# prevent go to the top page

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scroll go to the top page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448962/scroll-go-to-the-top-page)

Hi all

please how i can prevent go to the top page when post back page (asp.net)

Comment: Explain what you mean "go to the top page" - what page? What you mean by the word "top" in this context? Currently it's not a real question.

Comment: Please edit your original question.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about webform, you can set MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack in the Page directive and the framework looks after it for you.

```
<% Page Language ="C#"  MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" %>
```

Comment: i use it but does not work because i use web methods

Comment: not sure what you mean by that and why it doesnt work. If you have custom flow that works differently perhaps you can explore using js/jquery where you have more control on the logic.